# Is the number of childhood vaccines correlated with infant mortality?

Tags: medical-science, mortality, children, vaccines

**Related**

- [Just how inaccurate are vaccine myths?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/95/just-how-inaccurate-are-vaccine-myths)
- [Is it dangerous to have several vaccines at the same time?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/328/is-it-dangerous-to-have-several-vaccines-at-the-same-time)

---

I was passed along an article reporting that a new study found that despite having the highest number of vaccines in its recommended schedule, the United States is ranked 34th in infant mortality rates (IMR) in the world.

Mercola presents this [**here**](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2011/06/20/uk-scraps-pneumonia-vaccines-because-they-dont-work.aspx).

The report abstract is [**here**](http://het.sagepub.com/content/early/2011/05/04/0960327111407644) and the full text is [**here**](http://het.sagepub.com/content/early/2011/05/04/0960327111407644.full.pdf+html).

From the conclusion:

> A closer inspection of correlations between vaccine doses, biochemical or synergistic toxicity, and IMRs, is essential. All nations—rich and poor, advanced and developing—have an obligation to determine whether their immunization schedules are achieving their desired goals.

Here's their plots of number of vaccines in a country's schedule with infant mortality rate.

[image: IMR vs. number of vaccines]

In other words, I take this to mean that they are suggesting that vaccine toxicity has a causal relationship to infant deaths, or that the vaccines are innefective, despite a high number in one's scheduled dosage recommendations.

I immediately wondered what contributes to infant mortality rate. Is it just vaccine-preventable illnesses and the paper is suggesting incorrectly that vaccines are ineffective? Do deaths during delivery count... and can those even possibly be related to vaccination schedules?

They mention that there are 130 categories of infant deaths:

> Many nations adhere to an agreed upon International Classification of Diseases (ICD) for grouping infant deaths into 130 categories. Among the 34 nations analyzed, those that require the most vaccines tend to have the worst IMRs. Thus, we must ask important questions: is it possible that some nations are requiring too many vaccines for their infants and the additional vaccines are a toxic burden on their health?

They only discuss SIDS as a potential vaccine side effect; I would be curious to know what the other 130 categories are and whether or not they have a possibility of being related to vaccines.

They mention some limitations here...

> This analysis did not adjust for vaccine composition, national vaccine coverage rates, variations in the infant mortality rates among minority races, preterm births, differences in how some nations report live births, or the potential for ecological bias. A few comments about each of these factors are included below

This followed by a discussion of why they don't think these categories would sway the results [much].

---

**My Questions:**

- Is this paper's methodology/conclusion sound? Is there a valid concern here about a potential causal relationship between vaccines and infant mortality rates?
- Are there studies that have alternative explanations to why the US infant mortality is high compared to similarly developed nations?

Comment: +1 question greatly asked, and I hope it will settle a lot of misinformation on this subject.

Comment: The high infant mortality in the US has another reason: Too many parents refrain from seeking medical attention because they buy into either new-age woo or fundamentalist religion, which in some jurisdictions does not count as harmful neglect...

Comment: +1 What a great question. I hope it attracts an answer of similar quality!

Comment: @Lagerbaer: I'd be thrilled for you to provide sources for this and illustrate the high contribution from such causes to the IMR.

Comment: @Lagerbaer:  Unfortunately most of these "alternative remedies" don't have any studies to back them up (let alone peer-reviewed studies), and the government doesn't seem to be shutting them down despite their ridiculous claims; here's a helpful page from a web site that many alternative health scam promoters seem to despise:  _Twenty-Five Ways to Spot Quacks and Vitamin Pushers_ -- http://www.quackwatch.org/01QuackeryRelatedTopics/spotquack.html

Comment: Countries that require the most Vaccines also have the best tracking of IMR.  In developing countries with no vaccines when a child dies it is buried and no one ticks the box most of the time.

Comment: The binning of data in the graph on the right is arbitrary and unjustified.

Comment: The title of the question asks about correlation, but the body asks about "potential causal relationship". The answer could be Yes and No, if, for example, the USA's health care system promoted healthful vaccinations AND inadequate healthcare otherwise for uninsured infants.

Comment: @Oddthinking Good point, and while I asked about correlation... you are correct that I really only care about causation! With your followup question, do you mean that uninsured infants might be provided vaccines but no other types of care? This could definitely be the case, but it would be good to see evidence that those types of stipulations exist in some plans.

Comment: @Hendy: yes, evidence is needed before accepting that claim and I have none. I offered it merely as a hypothetical to demonstrate how correlation and causation might be different in thus case.

Comment: Be mindful of spurious correlations http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations (assuming that the claimed correlation actually exists and the figures haven't been made up)

Comment: @Chad, you make a good point but this study excluded poor countries from consideration. This study was exclusively about countries with low infant mortality. There are dozens of countries with more than 10 times the average infant mortality of countries considered by this study.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The first author [Neil Z Miller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Z._Miller) is the director of the [Thinktwice Global Vaccine Institute](http://www.thinktwice.com/), which is decidedly anti-vaccination as a short look at their website will confirm. He also published a series of books on vaccination. This does not mean the paper is necessarily biased, but it is an undisclosed conflict of interest which is not a good sign.

They are also not providing any evidence for causation, the linear regression graphs in your question is essentially the whole analysis the authors performed.

There is an [excellent deconstruction of this specific study by David Gorkski on the Scienced Based Medicine blog](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/index.php/vaccine-schedules-and-infant-mortality-a-false-relationship-promoted-by-the-anti-vaccine-movement/). I recommend to read the whole article, I will only summarize a few points here.

David Gorski also notes the conflict of interest that I observed when I researched the first author. One aspect he point out is that the authors used only the data for one year (2009) and only for countries with IMR lower than the United States.

> Miller and Goldman only looked at one
> year’s data. There are many years
> worth of data available; if such a
> relationship between IMR and vaccine
> doses is real, it will be robust,
> showing up in multiple analyses from
> multiple years’ data. Moreover, the
> authors took great pains to look at
> only the United States and the 33
> nations with better infant mortality
> rates than the U.S. There is no
> statistical rationale for doing this,
> nor is there a scientific rationale.
> Again, if this is a true correlation,
> it will be robust enough to show up in
> comparisons of more nations than just
> the U.S. and nations with more
> favorable infant mortality rates.
> Basically, the choice of data analyzed
> leaves a strong suspicion of cherry
> picking.

When I saw the graph on the right with the grouped data I was suspicious as I could not see any reason to arbitrarily group the data. It looked like a cheap way to make the plot look better, not like an analysis that would actually provide more insight. David Gorsky shares my suspicion and notes

> More dubiously, for some reason the
> authors, not content with an weak and
> not particularly convincing linear
> relationship in the raw data, decided
> to do a little creative data
> manipulation and divide the nations
> into five groups based on number of
> vaccine doses, take the means of each
> of these groups, and then regraph the
> data. Not surprisingly, the data look
> a lot cleaner, which was no doubt why
> this was done, as it was a completely
> extraneous analysis. As a rule of
> thumb, this sort of analysis will
> almost always produce a much
> nicer-looking linear graph, as opposed
> to the “star chart” in Figure 1.

As pointed out by [Catharina from the Just the Vax blog](http://justthevax.blogspot.com/2011/05/oh-goodness-here-i-wanted-to-go-to-bed.html), the paper also contains an error regarding the german vaccination schedule. [The German Childhood Vaccination Schedule](http://www.euvac.net/graphics/euvac/vaccination/germany.html) recommends additionally Hepatitis B from birth on, as well as MMR and Chickenpox vaccinations starting at 11 months.

There are other studies that examined the association of SIDS (sudden infant death syndrome) and vaccinations, **a [meta analysis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17400342) concluded that vaccinations help to prevent SIDS**

> Immunisations are associated with a
> halving of the risk of SIDS. There are
> biological reasons why this
> association may be causal, but other
> factors, such as the healthy vaccinee
> effect, may be important.
> Immunisations should be part of the
> SIDS prevention campaigns.

### US infant mortality rate

There is a report from the CDC addressing the high infant mortality rate in the United States: [Behind International Rankings of Infant Mortality: How the United States Compares with Europe](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/databriefs/db23.htm).

> - Infant mortality rates for preterm (less than 37 weeks of gestation)
>   infants are lower in the United States
>   than in most European countries;
>   however, infant mortality rates for
>   infants born at 37 weeks of gestation
>   or more are higher in the United
>   States than in most European
>   countries.
> - One in 8 births in the United States were born preterm, compared with 1 in
>   18 births in Ireland and Finland.
> - If the United States had Sweden’s distribution of births by gestational
>   age, nearly 8,000 infant deaths would
>   be averted each year and the U.S.
>   infant mortality rate would be
>   one-third lower.
> - The main cause of the United States’ high infant mortality rate when
>   compared with Europe is the very high
>   percentage of preterm births in the
>   United States.

The conclusion is that the higher rate of preterm infants explains a large part of the higher infant mortality rate, but not the whole discrepancy between Europe and the United States.

The following figure shows the IMR comparison if you exclude births earlier than 22 weeks, the US rate is significantly lower, but still higher than in most european countries.

[image]

> However, infant mortality rates for
> infants born at 37 weeks of gestation
> or more are generally higher in the
> United States than in European
> countries.

The report does not speculate what the source of the remaining difference between Europe and US infant mortality rate could be.

### Conclusion

The whole paper looks more like a fishing expedition to me than a thorough and objective analysis. They used an arbitrarily limited subset of the available data and did not correct for any potential confounding factors. This looks suspiciously like they played around with the data until they found the correlation they searched for, especially given the known bias of the authors.

Comment: Fantastic answer -- thanks for all that digging! I did find it odd that the US IMR for pre 37 weeks birth is *lower* than European rates... but just a few points down it says that our IMR is higher *because* we have a lot of pre 37 week births. The overall IMR for pre-term births must still be quite a bit higher than full term, then, right?

Comment: Nice answer ! Here is another article highlighting flaws in the mentioned study: http://scienceblogs.com/insolence/2011/05/16/vaccines-and-infant-mortality-rates/

Comment: @M.G.Palmer: Just to let you know, Respectful Insolence is the not-so-secret (it's more or less a running joke that it's "secret") blog by Dr. Gorski, who wrote the SBM paper mentioned above. Mainly mentioning it so that no one chimes in with a "Those two articles are *suspiciously* similar..." comment. :)

Comment: What would the chart look like if we did use the average infant mortality for a wider range of western countries over a larger number of years? That could be a very convincing refutation of the Mercola claims.

Comment: Great answer. So do we know why the USA has so many more preemies?

Comment: @Hendy What's going on is that the US is better at handling preemies but our overall stats are worse because we have more preemies.

Comment: @Loren_Pechtel so basically, more preemeies are born because of better capacity to handle them, but because they then have a much higher fatality rate, it artificially inflates the infant mortality rate?

Comment: Has anyone been able to find any graph of infant mortality versus vaccines that **wasn't** made by Neil Z. Miler? Because I couldn't. Seems like this shouldn't be hard to do - aren't there some anti-anti-vaxxer scientists out there? Certainly on a **temporal** scale, anyone can see that infant mortality has gone down over the last century while vaccination rates have gone up... but I prefer a direct response based on more data.

Comment: @Zibbobz There's also a problem with the data.  Infant mortality + stillbirth rates are much flatter than infant mortality rates.  That **strongly** suggests the infant mortality rates aren't being correctly reported.

Comment: Another chart that should be provided for context is the comparison of infant mortality before vaccination was common with the mortality after it became common.

Comment: @LorenPechtel or that there are differences in reporting requirements between countries that cause a difference where there is none. E.g. if one country calls it stillborn only if the baby leaves the womb dead while another terms it such if it dies within the first 10 minutes, there's a difference right there in the data that doesn't reflect an actual difference in instances. This makes all such comparisons very difficult.

Comment: @jwenting I do agree a lot of it is standards (although more subtle--any sign of life vs taking a breath for example), I'm simply showing there's a problem with the data without worrying about the cause.  Trying to use bad data as an input makes for garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @LorenPechtel true. Wasn't attacking your argument, merely pointing to other reasons why different numbers can turn up even from the same data.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to what Mad Scientist said,

- The neonatal infant mortality rate (first 28 days) is [generally much higher](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm5714a6.htm) than the post-neonatal infant mortality rate, yet this is [before most vaccines are administered](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/schedules/hcp/imz/child-adolescent.html). So why did Miller choose to compare "number of vaccines" to *total* infant mortality instead of *post-neonatal* infant mortality?
- And why not consider 5-year mortality - data which is very easy to get? If Miller means to imply that vaccines cause **immediate** death and not death within 5 years, why hasn't anyone but him and his research partner noticed?
- The study only includes countries with low infant mortality rates (specifically in 2009, unlike, say, Wikipedia which offers [five-year averages for the last 65 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_infant_and_under-five_mortality_rates)). OECD countries like Mexico and Turkey with high infant mortality are excluded. There are dozens of countries with more than 10 times the average infant mortality of countries in this study.

Obviously, there is reason to suspect that the correlation reverses when more countries are added, more years are added, when post-neonatal mortality is considered, when deaths with a known cause are excluded or when parental wealth and other factors are controlled for. But someone needs to actually go out, gather the data and redo the analysis - googling, I didn't find any other study on this. I couldn't even find an effort to reproduce or refute the results with easily-located data.

Comment: Isn't it considered polite to leave a comment explaining why you are downvoting someone's very first post?

Comment: It's likely because answers are expected to stand on their own, not as supplements to another answer.

Comment: @Erik this adds enough new information and is too long for a comment (plus comments can't be nicely formatted), so posting it as an answer is appropriate. If this site were a wiki you'd add it as a paragraph to the article, but the SE format doesn't allow for that.

Comment: As to your first point, vaccines during pregnancy could be related to infant mortality.  The flu vaccine during pregnancy has been added to the CDC list in the US.  Also, it's not clear how common it is to give a vaccine like HepB on the first day of life.